# ImportError: cannot import name 'certs'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, importerror

I'm having this error for the last 2 days. It seems a problem with python requests library, but I've re-installed it several times with no luck.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "project-src/bla-blah/manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
    File "project-src\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
    File "project-src\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 354, in execute
    django.setup()
    File "project-src\env\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 21, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
    File "project-src\env\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
    File "project-src\env\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 112, in create
    mod = import_module(mod_path)
    File "C:\Python34\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
    File "project-src\env\lib\site-packages\social\apps\django_app\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from social.apps.django_app.utils import load_strategy
    File "project-src\env\lib\site-packages\social\apps\django_app\utils.py", line 12, in <module>
    from social.backends.utils import get_backend
    File "project-src\env\lib\site-packages\social\backends\utils.py", line 2, in <module>
    from social.backends.base import BaseAuth
    File "project-src\env\lib\site-packages\social\backends\base.py", line 1, in <module>
    from requests import request, ConnectionError
    File "project-src\env\lib\site-packages\requests\__init__.py", line 58, in <module>
    from . import utils
    File "project-src\env\lib\site-packages\requests\utils.py", line 24, in <module>
    from . import certs

    ImportError: cannot import name 'certs'
```

Maybe it's a problem with Windows 7 update from 2 days ago, because is the only thing that has changed in the last few days.

By the way, I'm using python 3.4 with virtualenv, PyCharm 3.4.1 IDE and Win7.

Inside **certs.py** there is the code that has the problem (last line):

```
try:
    from certifi import where
except ImportError:
    def where():
        """Return the preferred certificate bundle."""
        # vendored bundle inside Requests
        return os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'cacert.pem')
```

Comment: Perhaps you should post this on the requests issue tracker.

Comment: Good point, I'll ask there too. Thank you!

Comment: what version of requests are you using?

Comment: the last one: requests 2.4.3

Comment: In certs.py https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/certs.py I don't understand what the problem is. This is saying that it can't import certs. What happens when you do: `python -c 'import requests; print(requests.__version__)'`?

Comment: On ubuntu with fresh start everything goes ok, but not on windows. Same with Mac Os X. I  uninstalled every windows update package, just in case, and it's still failing. I also reinstalled python, and the virtualenv several times. I also try to launch the server inside and outside PyCharm: from command line.   :(

Comment: So here's the thing that doesn't make sense to me @davyria: When you run the command that you ran above, you're importing certs as well because that's imported by `utils` in `requests/__init__.py`. You should also be able to do `python -c 'from requests import certs; print(certs.where())'` without a problem either. That tells me something is broken somewhere else and that this is not a requests issue.

Comment: You're right, when I do the last line you sent me @sigmavirus24, it prints    `MY_PROYECT_PATH\env\lib\site-packages\certifi\cacert.pem`. I don't know what else to do, so... I think I will install another OS. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you're wondering what happened with this problem... I re-installed the operating system, downloaded the git project again, re-configured the python virtualenv and 'magically' it worked. So I'm sure there was a miss-configuration somewhere, but it wasn't requests library problem.

If you have the same problem, I encourage you to install a fresh environment.

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me (re-install requests library):

`pip uninstall requests
pip install requests`

Comment: Some issue with macOS Mojave package auto updates it seems. Not sure. But, I uninstalled requests 2.18.x version and installed latest 2.22.x version, and it worked for me.

Comment: This should be the answer !

Answer (score 1):

I had also the same problem last week on my Mac (Sierra). Besides, the `certs.py` module exists, which means that's a problem somehow related to the OS and not to Python itself. In my case, it was a problem of the max files limits, So just increase it with `ulimit 200000 200000`